# How to resolve "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED" with status code: 8 on Google cloud disk insert method

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am making api request to create disks to the Google Cloud platform and get status code as 200.so but when i check if disk is ready i get that "error":{"code":404 ,"reason":"notFound","domain":"global"}.
when i check google cloud logs i see for request the below error code.
"status": {
"code": 8,
"message": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"
}
-can anyone help possible solutions for this like which exact quota limit should be increased? i have tried retry mechanism with pause included abt 3 sec's with that i was able to reduce the probability but the real issue still there.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain two concepts in GCP that can be a bit confusing: Quotas and Limits

- Quotas are values that usually can be modified and adjusted to your infrastructure needs. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota) you have a document that explains how to work with Quotas. This Quotas have "limits", that as said usually can be modified.
- Limits are values enforced and they can’t be modified, and perhaps you reached an [API Limit](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits).

You can check in [this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) if you have reached any limit in your Quotas. Or accessing console.cloud.google.com, then clicking on the menu "Home -> IAM & Admin -> Quota”. Then you will see a list with all the quotas.

If you notice you reached a quota, you can request an increase by clicking on it, and then click on “Edit.” It will prompt a formulary that you will need to fulfill in order to request the modification of the quota.

You could also check the number of request you made using [Cloud Logging](http://console.cloud.google.com/logs/) with this filter: protoPayload.serviceName="compute.googleapis.com" protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.disks.insert"

It will show only the entries from Compute Engine, using the API Method v1.compute.disks.insert

Regards